# How to use biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, tutorials

Simply put I want to know what steps I need to take to start `biber` with `biblatex`. I haven't been able to find any proper tutorials or guides showing how you go about using it instead of BibTeX.

- What is `biber`'s syntax?
- How do you compile?
- Etc.

Are there any tutorials or guides available?

Comment: Related question: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)

Comment: `biber` is a replacement for BibTeX; you should use the `backend=biber` option when loading `biblatex`. Type `biber --help` in a terminal to get basic documentation.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Comment: I made a tutorial regarding the first steps:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=405t1qLEVCw

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Here is a MWE (not really minimum, but showing some options) that should get you started.
Other possible values for the `biblatex` options are described in the [biblatex documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sigfridsson}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

To compile you should now call `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`.
`biber` operates on the `.bcf` file, so either use `biber %.bcf` or (even better) just `biber %`, where `%` stands for the basename of your main `.tex` file.

`biblatex-examples.bib` is a file that comes with your TeX distribution, you can find it at `TEXMF/bibtex/bib/biblatex.biblatex-examples.bib`or [online](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib). It can be used for testing. Use a different filename for your own `.bib` file.

The `natbib=true` option allows you to use `citep` and `citet` style citations in you text. This is mainly for compatibility with old code. For new code, use `\textcite{}` and `\parencite{}` instead. `biblatex` knows some more cite commands like `\autocite{}` or `\footcite{}`. These are described in the [biblatex documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: @matth: Could you please tell me why your MWE doesn't work for me? https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/biblatex-mwe - I compile it with the Makefile

Comment: @moose See my updated answer, if that doesn't help, ask again.

Comment: @matth: I am using texlive 2016 and TexShop 3.77 with OS X 10.12.4 Compiling the example code above with pdf latex I get the following error: (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...blx@datamodel@fields}{date}}\StrCut 
                                                  {date}{date}\blx@datetype ...
l.585   urldate}

Comment: @HeinzM. Sorry, I do not know what that message means. Try cleaning the project, delete the .aux and .bbl files, try updating all your Tex Live packages and compile agian. Did you search the internet already? Maybe submit a bug report!?

Comment: @NicHartley It does print a bibliography on my computer, and seems to work well for many others. Do you get any error messages? Did you follow all steps?

Comment: @matth Nope, as it turns out I didn't. (I thought I ran `pdflatex` before and after, I didn't.) My bad.

Answer (score 35):

run `texdoc biber` from the command line and you'll get the documentation. However, using `biber` as a replacement for `bibtex` you have to define the backend with

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,...]{biblatex}
```

and then change your `bibtex` run into a `biber` one, that is all.

However, with the latest `biblatex` package (TeXLive 2016) the `backend=biber` setting is the default, you have only to specify `bibtex` or `bibtex8` if you want to use one of the old programs. And, of course,  you have to change the program name in your editor. For example: in TeXstudio it is Options->Configure->Build->Standard Bibprogram->biber.

Comment: So you continue using the same syntax as `bibtex` uses?

Comment: @benreqn. Could you specify which syntax you mean? In the LaTeX document, things stay the same apart from the `biblatex` changes. In the `.bib` file, things stay the same although one or two fields are renamed.

Comment: in general yes. There is only a need for parameters if your document is of another encoding as the bib data file is.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: By syntax I mean the markup of the `.bib` file. E.g. @article{keyword, title="Spy vs. Spy"}

Comment: No, there are no changes needed to the .bib file. Biber is functionally a superset of bibtex so there are more things you can do with it (see the "biber only" parts of the bibalatex manual and the biber manual itself).

Comment: @benregn It took me a while to figure this out but when Herbert said to "change your bibtex run into a biber one", you may need to change the default script that your program is running.  The biber manual gives an example for EMacs and TeXWorks but in TeXShop you go to the engine tab and change the bibtex engine to biber. Also, I had to use bibfile.bib (instead of just bibfile) for it to find my library. Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Did you pass the bibfile data via the command line to biber? If yes, then it is obvious that you need the extension.

Comment: I think it is still good style to have `backend=biber` even though Biber is now the standard backend if only to avoid the warning `No "backend" specified, using Biber backend`. It also makes things more explicit for people reading the code.

Comment: @moewe:  set in a config file `bibwarn=false`. And I do not think so that it makes sense. There is nowadays absolute no reason for using `bibtex/bibtex8/bibtexu`. They all have too many regressions.

Answer (score 1):

I took the `biblatex.pdf` and read my way through and it is well organized!

You must set a customer-defined command (analog to how I had to set `makeglossaries.exe`) but with `biber(.sh/.exe)`, which should be installed in your LaTeX manager.

I had to add this to the custom commands so biber is found properly.

```
"path/to/biber(.sh/.exe)" %
```

Especially interesting is

#### `1.5 Prerequisites`

- tells you what packages you need and in which order to load the
  dependencies
- apparently depending on the biblatex version you might need another
  biber version

#### `3.1 Package Options`

- what settings can I apply

#### `3.14.1 Overview`

- step-by-step example with code snippet how to use biber

See [@matth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8569/matth)'s post for example syntax
In the end you build

- (I recommend to clean aux files when running stuff like that)
- `pdflatex %`
- `biber %`
- `pdflatex %`

Comment: Virtually everyone has Biber and Biblatex installed if they have TeX installed. If you don't have them, but you have TeX installed, you should install Biblatex and Biber using your TeX distribution's tools if you installed it directly (e.g. downloaded TeX Live or MikTeX) or your OS distro's package manager (if that's how you installed TeX). If you don't have TeX installed, you should install a TeX distribution since Biblatex and Biber are useless without it. You should download a Biber executable directly only for testing purposes - not production. PS Not everyone uses Windows.

Comment: I did overlook that biber is installed by default indeed. For the other points - I did understand the question in the way that the person would like to know how to proceed and at least I had some trouble with perl and the default settings for makeglossaries and all. Once a LaTeX editor works like a charm it is easy, but sometimes the getting there is the hard part. Well not everyone uses Linux, not everyone uses a LaTex editor...