# Problem: Different authors result in same citation symbol

Tags: biblatex

**Behavior**: Using biblatex's *alphabetic* style, I'm citing "Mr. Stark" and "Stack Exchange Inc.", both of 2010. In both cases I get [Sta10] as a reference symbol.

**Problem**: The reader cannot know whom I'm citing.

**Desired behavior**: I'd like different reference symbols, for instance [Sta10a] and [Sta10b]. (This actually works when it's the same author, but not when the authors are different.)

Any hints are highly appreciated. Thank you!

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{same_but_different.bib}
@misc{A, author = {{Stack Exchange Inc.}}, year = {2010}}
@misc{B, author = {Starck, Erik}, year = {2010}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{same_but_different}

\begin{document}

\emph{Stark} claims something \cite{A} to which \emph{Stack Exchange} cannot agree \cite{B}.
Unfortunately, they get the same citition symbol. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Result**:
[image: The result of my problematic example]

Comment: Note that in `biblatex`, `\bibliography` is deprecated, the use of `\addbibresource` (with the `.bib` file extension) instead is recommended. See section 3.5.1 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `biber` instead of `bibtex` you can do this easily:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    uniquename=true
]{biblatex}
```

Other possible values for `uniquename` are described in the [biblatex documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

This option only works with biber, not with bibtex. 
The switch is easy, where you now call `bibtex.exe`, replace it with `biber.exe`. 
Your compilation procedure would then be `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`.
More detailed instructions are here: [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber) and [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex).

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot! Would you be able to include your comment -- switch to biber -- into the answer so that it is complete?

Comment: I added the comment to the original answer and deleted the comment.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it provides an automatic solution, making the whole process less error-prone. However, please take note of @Tobi's comment  uli's answer: "I’d prefer something like SX10 for the Stack Exchange citation, cause Sta10a and Sta10b will look like they are from the same author". In that case, uli's answer provides a way to override the generated names. Both can be used in combination. So thank you both!

Comment: One thing to note for the future also is that biber also allows users to completely customise the template/format of the label but that functionality isn't exposed in biblatex yet - will probably be in biblatex 2.x.

Answer (score 15):

According to the `biblatex` documentation you could use a `shorthand` to overwrite the default label, and help biblatex here.

```
@misc{A, shorthand = {Sta10a}, author = {{Stack Exchange Inc.}}, year = {2010}}
@misc{B, shorthand = {Sta10b}, author = {Starck, Erik}, year = {2010}}
```

Comment: @FelixAlcala: I’d prefer something like SX10 for the Stack Exchange citation, cause Sta10a and Sta10b will look like they are from the same author …

Comment: @Tobi: good point!