# Using biber with gedit + rubber

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, biber, rubber

I've been having a lot of problems trying to switch to `biblatex` with `biber` from `bibtex`, and after a few problems solved I'm at loss. The situation now:

- `biblatex` works when not using `biber` as a backend
- `biber` is installed (When I run `biber --version` I get `biber version: 0.9.8`)
- When running `rubber` (via the `gedit` latex plugin) on a document with `biber` as backend, nothing happens. I get no error, the document is continuously compiling but never finishes.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{geometry}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{bilbliography}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm running Fedora 16 and Gnome 3. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you should try running `biber` from the command line on a real file (e.g., `biber myfile.bcf`) and see what kind of messages `biber` gives you (it is quite verbose).  Also it looks like it has changed since version 0.9.6, but I need to add the .bib extension to my bibliography files (I'm guessing the optional argument takes now care of that, however).

Comment: Yes, I'll try that. I already tried to run it on my bibliography `biber bibliography.bib` but that gave me a concerned error about me not having run it through `biblatex` first. So I'm not quite sure in which order to run commands with `biber` and `biblatex` (and was kinda hoping `rubber` would do it for me). Would you reccomend me to upgrade the bibliography to `.bfc` which I assume is the biblatex form?

Comment: PLK's answer should solve your problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You don't need to add the `[datatype=bibtex]` option to `\addbibresource` - that's the default
2. You need the full filename e.g. `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`. The optional arguments don't help with this.
3. Biber is not run on the `.bib` file, it's run on the `.bcf` file which is produced when you use the `backend=biber` option to biblatex. You can call biber on this file with or without the `.bcf` file extension.

Comment: I imagine there must be some issue with the `gedit LaTeX plugin` and biber, but with this answer I least successfully compiled the document on `emacs` with `AUCTeX`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** This answer might be considered a hack, so there's no garantee to work for every document. `:)`</sup>

egreg and I were talking in the [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) chat room about the possibility of extending `rubber` to use `biber`. This answer is only possible because of his insight. Grazie mille, egreg. `:)`

First of all, note that `rubber` does not seem to be maintained anymore. The latest stable version - which is `1.1` - was released in 2006. IMHO the development version is far from usable.

`rubber` can be extended through modules. Plain and simple, a `rubber` module is a Python script following certain rules. Unfortunately, those modules are quite "rare" to find.

I wrote a [post in our community blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/) about `rubber`. There's a nice usage of a module. For example, `rubber` offers no XeLaTeX support out of the box, but thankfully Wouter Bolsterlee provided an elegant solution by writing a module for it.

That said, I'll document the process I did just for completeness sake.

`rubber` has a `rules/latex` directory where you can find other modules. I'm also on Fedora 16, the location of this directory is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rubber/rules/latex
```

My approach here is to use a similar module and adjust it to our purpose. If we list `rules/latex`, we find a `bibtex.py` file there which is registered in the `__init__.py` - it means `rubber` assumes `bibtex` by default.

What I did was copying `bibtex.py` to a new file `biber.py`. Since both programs seem to work similarly, I assume it's only a matter of replacing one by the other. Again, I had no time to inspect the file, so it's far from being stable or bullet proof! Besides, `biber` might have some other particularities which are not covered in this approach.

I opened `biber.py` - which is an exact copy of `bibtex.py` and searched for occurrences of `bibtex`, replacing it by `biber`, including messages and the system call. I kept the function names intact - but nothing that a proper refactoring can solve.

OK, now I have the module. Now I need a test document. I've never used `biber` before, so I had to rely on the following MWE from [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sigfridsson}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Now, in my terminal, I navigated to my test directory with both `document.tex` and `mybib.bib`. I called the following command:

```
$ rubber --module=biber document
```

It's also possible to add a `rubber` directive in the top of the `.tex` file in order to call this module:

```
% rubber: module biber
\documentclass[]{article}
...
```

The output:

[image: Running Biber with rubber]

I checked the resulting `document.pdf` and all references were correctly displayed.

This dirty hack would require more tests, but so far it seems to work. `:)`

Comment: I think `latexmk` is generally the most used automatic wrapper now and it certainly supports biber. It comes with TeXLive too I think.

Comment: @PLK: Indeed. `:)` I'd say `latexmk` is the natural choice. `rubber` is a nice tool (I really like it), but the lack of support for new engines/packages is something that worries me. Writing new modules seems to be feasible, but I don't think it's a trivial task for the casual user. `:(`

Comment: Haha, brilliant. This actually worked. But I hadn't realised rubber was such an outdated package. I guess I'll have a look at latexmk then, see how I like it. Thanks for the hack ;).

Comment: There is something very weird happening: `rubber` only calls the module if I call with the `--pdf` option, and it has to be before the module option, i.e., `rubber --pdf --module=biber document` works, but `rubber --module=biber --pdf document` dosen't. Otherwise your hack is just fine.

Comment: @MateusAraújo: It's been a while since I wrote this, but I suspect that the `bibtex` rule in which I based my hack might require the `--pdf` format - I'm not sure though. `:)` And about the arguments order, I guess I have a better explanation: if I recall correctly, there's a note somewhere in the `rubber` manual which states that the arguments order matters, so that would explain why the module isn't called (maybe because `--pdf` is set later on, and the module depends on this condition). I'll take a look. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to define rubber rules in the main tex file so that when the file is compiled and auxiliary files are produced/changed the biber command is triggered.

I have this in the top of my main.tex file:

```
% rubber: watch main.acn
% rubber: onchange main.acn 'makeglossaries main'

% rubber: watch main.bcf 
% rubber: onchange main.bcf 'biber main'
```

The first two lines are related with glossaries package (which I use to produce acronyms) and the second two lines are the ones necessary to call biber instead of the regular bibtex.

Do not forget that the backend=biber option is required in biblatex for this to work.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

I hope this is useful!