# Biblatex citation order

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm facing a problem with biblatex citation order.

Using this configuration:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\hyphenation{es-ta-bi-li-da-de}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{frameworks.bib}
```

Being frameworks.bib this:

```
@Article{JONHSON88,
author = {Ralph Johnson, Brian Foote},
title = {Designin Reusable Classes},
journal = {Journal of Object-Oriented Programming SIGS},
year = {1988},
key = {Johnson:88},
volume = {1},
number = {5},
pages = {22-35},
month = jun
}

@book{UML-F:00,
author = {Fontoura M., Pree W., Rumpe B.},
editor = {Addison-Wesley},
title = {The UML Profile for Framework Architectures},
year = {2000},
}
```

The PDF is generated with a text like:

```
Something about something[4], and moo foo other children[1].
```

This citation `[4]` is the first in all text. How can I order this correctly to `[1]...[2] ...`?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `sorting=none` option. 
Here is a fully working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    %backend=biber, 
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
   Aksin~\cite{aksin} says one in his article.
   Aristotle~\cite{aristotle:poetics} says two in his book.
   Angenendt~\cite{angenendt} says three in his article.
   And Augustine \cite{augustine} says four in his book.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

From section 3.1.2 of the [biblatex documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):
`biblatex` knows various schemes for sorting, these are:

- `nty` Sort by name, title, year.
- `nyt` Sort by name, year, title.
- `nyvt` Sort by name, year, volume, title.
- `anyt` Sort by alphabetic label, name, year, title.
- `anyvt` Sort by alphabetic label, name, year, volume, title.
- `ynt` Sort by year, name, title.
- `ydnt` Sort by year (descending), name, title.
- `none` Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order.
- `debug` Sort by entry key. This is intended for debugging only.

If sorting still fails, try [`backend=biber`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber), it is more stable especially with UTF8 .bib files.
Instead of calling `(pdf)latex`, `bibtex`, `(pdf)latex`, `(pdf)latex` 
you would then instead call `(pdf)latex`, `biber`, `(pdf)latex`.

Comment: Even doing this, the books are coming first. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch to `backend=biber` instead of `backend=bibtex`? Then take a look at my updated MWE. Maybe it helps.

Comment: It works like a charm. What's the behavior change of this modification?

Comment: Good to hear it works. You can read more about `biber` on the [biber homepage](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) or here on this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib

Comment: Biber's sorting code is a lot more advanced than bibtex. It also allows custom sorting schemes, not just the built in biblatex defaults

Comment: I was wondering today why `sorting=none` wouldn't work for me. My first citation would still be a [24] and deleting all `.aux` files etc. didn't help. It turns out that I had 24 (!) unused entries in my `.bib` file. After deleting all unused entries, everything was fine. I figured I'd put that here, maybe it'll save someone some time.

Comment: You might want to want that especially with numeric styles it might be necessary to delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`, ...) after changing the `sorting` in order for the new settings to take effect properly.

Comment: Strange this happen here: even deleting all temporary files, resetting the biber cache and so on, the first `\cite` in the documents isn't `[1]`.