# In-text references are not alphabetically ordered

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa6

I am using BibLaTex with APA style and Biber backend.

The [example document of biblatex-apa](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) states that multiple in-text references should be automatically ordered complying the APA 6 style independent from the order of input in the `\cite` command.

However, this is not working for me. The references in the document are ordered as put in in the cite command.

E.g. `\textcite{AuthorC2001, AuthorA2001, AuthorB2001}` will be printed in the PDF as

> AuthorC (2001), AuthorA (2001), AuthorB (2001)

instead of

> AuthorA (2001), AuthorB (2001), AuthorC (2001)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took me hours to find the answer. However, I just stumbled across the following [posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order?rq=1).

Just put the option

```
 sortcites=true
```

in the the preamble.

E.g.:

```
 \usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: I too dug forever to find this posting: thank you! Note the posting linked does not discuss this option...

Comment: The linked posting does indeed not discuss this option. However, the posting somehow helped me -- magically -- to find the answer to my original question ;).