# How to arrange the bibliography item in the order we maintain to cite in our thesis?

Tags: bibliographies

I want my bibliography list order to follow the order of the citation. That is, the citations should not have the `bibitem` order, whereas the `bibitem`'s must follow the citations order. For instance, if I cite a book in my first page of my thesis, it should be the first item in the bibliography, and second cite must be in the second in the bibliography.

For example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum,biblatex}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{key2}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{key1}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem  This has to be my second reference in my list.
\bibitem  This has to be my first reference in my list.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

<sub>Feel free to edit this question. May be I am not conveying these things in a proper English.</sub>

Comment: [**Duplicate question**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order)

Comment: You can't use the thebiblibliography environment with biblatex. And if you want to use it, you will have to sort the bibitem manually.

Answer (score 3):

Using `biblatex` is a very good idea but then you have to use a `bib` file.

The advantage is double:  `biblatex` gives you a lot of parameters to define the layout of the bibliography and the `bib` file can be used for **more than one** LaTeX document.

You gave no concret examples for your book so have a look to this MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to include a example `bib` file in the mwe code; please notice that I used `biber`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %  <========================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, % bibtex  % bibtex or biber (prefered)
  natbib=true,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none  % none, nty % no sorting or standard sorting
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % calls bib file to create the bibliography

\begin{document}
We first cite Albert Einstein~\cite{einstein}, second~\cite{adams} and 
third the \LaTeX{} Companian~\cite{goossens}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With the option `sorting=none` the resulting bibliography follows your cites as you can see here:

[image]

Now only with changing the `biblatex` option `sorting=nyt` the resulting bibliography is sorted by the author names.
See here:

[image]

The order of the bib entrys in the bib file do not change the results.

Just a remark: You saw the character `ö` in my example bib file?  That's the reason I used utf-8 encoding (line 35 of MWE).  Then you should use `biber`, which can handle utf8 encoding.