# APA bibliography style with numbers

Tags: biblatex, biber

For my thesis I am using biber and biblatex to manage the bibliography. I would like to use the apa-style of referencing since this is highly recommended by my university.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{library.bib} % with extension
\begin{document}
blabla
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The small code hereabove can perfectly generate me the apa-style that I would like, however, I would like to add numbers to each entry in the bibliography since I am using numbers to reference in the text. This would make everything more clear to the reader. After some thorough googling I have not yet found an answer to this solution, I hope it is very simple.

Answer (score 9):

The APA style is not a numeric kind of style and you will most certainly forego proper APA compliance with this. You could simply look at using `style=numeric` all along.

But if you really want an APA-like numeric bibliography, use

```
\documentclass[11pt,]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=numeric, backend=biber,]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography page of the MWE]

Comment: thank you for sharing this answer/code. I was wondering, however, if it'd be possible to make the second (and any subsequent) line in each citation indented in relation to the first line so that it resembles a typical APA bibliography. And if so, what would be the necessary changes to achieve this?

Comment: @Ernesto Usually the indent is only necessary to visually distinguish one entry from the next. In a numeric bibliography that is not necessary since the entries are already sufficiently delineated via the label number in front. Adding additional indent would just cost space. I can't think of a quick solution now, so I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: This will sort the bibliography in the standard APA sorting. If you want a different sorting, e.g. sort by citation order, you will want to look at the `sorting` option. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small implementation to the answer
to switch in English or other change `\DeclareLanguageMapping{X}{X-apa}` and `\usepackage[british]{babel}`

```
sorting=none,citestyle=numeric
```

sorting => sort the biblio by the text order cit and citestyle => in the text but [number]
the code :

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}

%style APA avec un numéro devant 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}




\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
%\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\cite{essai1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the biblio in another file "biblio.bib"

```
@online{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    title  = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url    = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    year   = {2013},
    urldate = {2022-09-29},
    
}
 @online{essai1,
    author = {Pibasso, Achille Mbog},
   year =   {2021},
    title = {Le Cameroun s’imprègne du modèle de la microfinance allemande},
   urldate = {2022-09-29},
   month =  {2021-01-22},
    url =   {https://www.financialafrik.com/2021/01/22/le-cameroun-sempreigne-du-modele-de-la-microfinance-allemande/}
 }
```