# Problem Biblatex numeric apa style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to have numeric citation style in my main document, sorted in order and also at the end where the Bibliography is published, have it in Apa style with LastName, Firstname Year printed.

So far I got the numeric and sorting order right, but can't figure out how to get the apa style in the end, can someone help me ? In my tex file I got the following setting:

```
\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
,citestyle=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=none        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

By the way, I don't know why but it doesn't show also the last visited on when it's an online ressource. For example here is one entry in my bib file

```
@misc{wordnet, 
    title={WordNet: A Lexical Database for English}, 
    url={https://wordnet.princeton.edu/}, 
    urldate={2018-24-02}, 
    author={author not named}
 }
```

Comment: [This similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373336/apa-bibliography-style-with-numbers) might help you.

Also, it would be easier for people to help you if you could post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 3):

You can control the `citestyle` and `bibstyle` separately. So it is theoretically possible to have `citestyle=numeric-comp` and `bibstyle=apa`.

There are a few caveats, though

- `apa` needs the Biber backend, so you need to switch from `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber` and need to run Biber instead of BibTeX ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864))
- The bibliography environment will not be numbered if you only load `bibstyle=apa`, so you also need to load `numeric.bbx` again. Below this is done with

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
  \makeatother
  ```
- It is not recommended to mix the highly specialised `biblatex-apa` style with different styles.

Then

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber
,bibstyle=apa
,citestyle=numeric-comp
,sorting=none
,sortcites=true
,block=none
]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{wordnet, 
  title   = {WordNet: A Lexical Database for English}, 
  url     = {https://wordnet.princeton.edu/}, 
  urldate = {2018-02-24}, 
  author  = {author not named},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,wordnet}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives you

[image: [1] Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P//[2] author not named. (n.d.). Wordnet: A lexical database for english. Retrieved February 24, 2018, from https://wordnet.princeton.edu/]

Maybe it would be enough for you to combine `numeric-comp` with the standard `authoryear` bibstyle as in [Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864). In that case you could continue using BibTeX, even though I would recommend you switch to Biber anyway.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex
,bibstyle=authoryear
,citestyle=numeric-comp
,sorting=none
,sortcites=true
,block=none
]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{wordnet, 
  title   = {WordNet: A Lexical Database for English}, 
  url     = {https://wordnet.princeton.edu/}, 
  urldate = {2018-02-24}, 
  author  = {author not named},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,wordnet}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

The `urldate` issue is caused by a misformatted date: All dates must be given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and so `2018-24-02` is not a valid date. The 24 February 2018 is `2018-02-24`.

Comment: in this case its almost good. Except first name and last name is inverted. Is it your code or my bibtex, I defined it in it as author={Lastname, First letter from Firstname}

Comment: @Neon67 APA style wants "Lastname, F." in the output, so that is what you get here. If you don't want the output `style=apa` gets you I suggest you stick with normal `style=numeric`. Or maybe `style=authoryear` as in the second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You'll put just need to add `style=apa` in the `usepackage`, so it'll be like this:

```
\usepackage[%
style=apa           %to get the APA style
,backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
,citestyle=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=none        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

Comment: Note that just adding `style=apa` will remove the numbers from the bibliography which makes citations incredibly hard to find. Furthermore, `biblatex-apa` requires `backend=biber`, so the code shown here will throw the error: `! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.`