# bliblatex bibliography with apa and formating

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

Hello I get the following element

[image]

but I want before each reference [`1] [2]` and extra
like this exemple

[image]

my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    title  = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url    = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    month = {02-05},
    year   = {2013},
    urldate = {2022-09-29},
    
}
 @online{essai1,
    author = {Pibasso, Achille Mbog},
   year =   {2021},
    title = {Le Cameroun s’imprègne du modèle de la microfinance allemande},
   urldate = {2022-09-29},
   month =  {2021-01-22},
    url =   {https://www.financialafrik.com/2021/01/22/le-cameroun-sempreigne-du-modele-de-la-microfinance-allemande/}
  } 
 
 @article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
    month = {08},
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
 }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

  
   % formatting of hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}


\begin{document}
   
\cite{essai1} et \cite{ministerium} et\cite{einstein} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @johnvador.
Why don't you simply use
`\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you want here. APA style is an unnumbered style that uses author-year citations. If you want APA style, use `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` (and nothing else). If you want a numbered style, something like `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` is more appropriate. If you really need numbered APA, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373336/35864.,

Comment: I wanted the apa system because the formating reference like web page was respecting my requirements