# Start references from 1 overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

My references, in an article I'm working on, start from [13] and not [1]. How do I get it to start from [1]?

In my bibliography, at the bottom, it is in order but in the actual article itself it does not start in order from [1] onward.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` for this if you are using BibTeX (you need to remove the `\bibliographystyle` command that is in your document now and replace it with this one). `unsrt` (for 'unsorted') sorts references according to the order they appear in the document. If you use BibLaTeX instead of BibTeX then it works differently, for that see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order.

Comment: overleaf is not involved, that is just where you are running tex, The numbering depends on how you have specified your bibliography

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: in many disciplines the normal style is to list the bibliography in alphabetic order, and so the first reference in the document will have whatever number corresponds to that author, and not be [1]. In other disciplines references are ordered in order of citation (which always seem rather strange to me)