# sort bib entries in alphabetical order of auther, biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I use `biblatex` to create the formatted bibliography, and I want to order citations in an alphabetical order of auther's name and then publicated year by ascending. I post a picture to show what I want:
[image]

As we can see from above, the `style` is like `plain`,which is what I want.However, the order of references is not in an alphabetical order of auther.

I found several methods on the forum but none of them satisfy my needs.

I tried this, but it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting. Mainly, I've added the 'biblatex' tag and removed references to Overleaf, as your query is not really related to the fact that you compile your document on the Overleaf platform.

Comment: When you write that "I want to order citations in an alphabetical order", I assume you intend to sort the bibliographic entries alphabetically. Please advise if this interpretation of your statement is not correct.

Comment: I trust you have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864? You explicitly select a citation order that consider years before names (`ydnt` = years descending -> name -> title).

Comment: Any news here? It is not quite clear to me what result you want to obtain, what result you expected to obtain specifically from setting `sorring=ydnt,` and what result you did in fact obtain. There is also a possibly discrepancy between the title, which talks about the bib sorting order and the body of the questions, which mentions citation sorting order. Usually I would interpret citation sorting order as the order of citations in multi-cites like `\cite{sigfridsson,worman}`.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding! I do further research on `biblatex`, and find a useful [guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles) of using it on overleaf!  This guide solves my question!@moewe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote,

> I want to [sort the formatted bibliographic entries] in an alphabetical order.

In that case, you should replace `sorting=ydnt` with `sorting=nty`. (In fact, since `sorting=nty` is the default, you needn't specify it explicitly.)

The modified MWE (minimum working example) would thus be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Here are the predefined options for the `sorting` key, copied from p. 47 of the user guide of the `biblatex` package:

[image]