# Biblatex citation order problem with ausarbeitung class

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

The problem is that I cite some book and the cite number starts with 12 but I want the order how I cite ( first cite = 1, second = 2, etc.).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{ausarbeitung}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting = none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{latexlit.bib}
\newtheorem{Bsp}{Beispiel}[chapter]

\begin{document}

...
\cite{1}
\cite{2}
....

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
The package biblatex has already been loaded with options:
[toc=bib,style=numeric,backend=biber]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[toc=bib,style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting = none]
```

Adding the global options: `toc=bib,style=numeric,backend=biber,toc=bib,style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting = none`
but when I'm adding this, the problem is still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Biblatex citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order)

Comment: From the proposed duplicate: `\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric, sorting = none]{biblatex}` should work.

Comment: `sorting=none` should do what you want.

Comment: no guys it doesnt work, i get an error (see edit)

Comment: Regarding the error: you should only have one `\usepackage{biblatex}` statement, it appears you have two separate statements now. Also, when you have reduced it to one statement and you run without error, then you may need to run `biber` again and then LaTeX again to see the changes in the pdf.

Comment: You'll have to show us `ausarbeitung.cls` (where did you get it from?): Apparently it loads `biblatex` itself.

Comment: There is https://github.com/r4gus/Wahlprojekt/blob/master/ausarbeitung.cls from Hochschule Aalen, is that it? That class indeed loads `biblatex` with `toc=bib,style=numeric,backend=biber`. You can try putting `\PassOptionsToPackage{sorting=none}{biblatex}` on the top of your document (even before `\documentclass{ausarbeitung}`) and then remove the `\usepackage` statement from your code.

Comment: @Marijn, my guess is that your comment will very likely solve the problem. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to type up a quick answer here or do you want to close the question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order?

Comment: @moewe I'll answer, this one seems a bit different because of the class setup.

Answer (score 1):

To number the citations in the order that they appear in the document you can use the `sorting=none` option for `biblatex`.

However, the class `ausarbeitung` (from https://github.com/r4gus/Wahlprojekt/blob/master/ausarbeitung.cls) loads `biblatex` itself. If you try to load it again in the preamble of the document then the compilation will fail with the error `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package biblatex.`. In this case you can use the command `\PassOptionsToPackage` in your preamble before the package is loaded. In this case the package is loaded by the class, so the command should be placed before `\documentclass`.

MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{sorting=none}{biblatex}
\documentclass[oneside]{ausarbeitung}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{aksin}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{bertram}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I used `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography`, which is deprecated in `biblatex` (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) on page 88). For the citations I used `biblatex-examples.bib`, which is an example file that is pre-installed with each `biblatex` installation, so it is convenient for asking and answering questions because it is available for everybody.