# Author replaced with dash line in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, punctuation

I have referred in my thesis 4 abstracts from the same author:

```
@inproceedings{quantin2019exomars,
  title={ExoMars at Oxia Planum, probing the aqueous-related Noachian environments},
  author={Quantin-Nataf, C and Carter, J and Mandon, L and Balme, M and Fawdon, P and Davis, J and Thollot, P and Dehouck, E and Pan, L and Volat, M and others},
  booktitle={Ninth International Conference on Mars Abstracts},
  volume={6317},
  year={2019}
}
@inproceedings{quantin2018unique,
  title={The unique and diverse record of Noachian aqueous activity in Oxia Planum, Mars},
  author={Quantin-Nataf, C and Thollot, P and Carter, J and Mandon, L and Dehouck, E},
  booktitle={Lunar and Planetary Science Conference},
  volume={49},
  year={2018}
}
@inproceedings{quantin2016oxia,
  title={Oxia Planum, the landing site for ExoMars 2018},
  author={Quantin, C and Carter, J and Thollot, P and Broyer, J and Lozach, L and Davis, Joel and Grindrod, Peter and Pajola, M and Baratti, E and Rossato, S and others},
  booktitle={47th Lunar and Planetary Science Conference Abstracts, Abstract},
  volume={2863},
  year={2016}
}
@article{quantin2015oxia,
  title={Oxia Planum: a suitable landing site for ExoMars 2018 Rover},
  author={Quantin, C and Carter, J and Thollot, P and Broyer, J and Lozach, L and Davis, Joel and Grindrod, Peter and Pajola, M and Baratti, E and Rossato, S and others},
  journal={EPSC Abstracts},
  volume={10},
  pages={EPSC2015--704},
  year={2015}
}
```

In my main.tex file for the bibliography I inserted:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

........

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
```

.........

```
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the end I have this result:
[image]

except for the dash line, there are not even in a year order.

Comment: Yes! thank you! But why do not they appear in year order too?

Comment: You use `sorting=nyt`, which means 'sort by Name, then Year, then Title'. You can change it into, e.g., `sorting=ynt`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order for more information.

Comment: You may want to consider adding dots to the initials so that `biblatex` can tell that you are giving initials and are not citing loads of people whose first name is only one letter (I've heard of some people whose first name *is* just one letter, but I doubt this is the case for all the authors you cite). So say `author={Quantin-Nataf, C. and Thollot, P. and Carter, J. and Mandon, L. and Dehouck, E.},` instead of `author={Quantin-Nataf, C and Thollot, P and Carter, J and Mandon, L and Dehouck, E},`. If you don't want the dots in the output that can be arranged, but they should be in the input.