# How to properly add the bibliography to my document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

**This is my TEX file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{cvetkovic2010towards} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{cvetkovic2010towards} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**This is my Bib file:**

```
@article{cvetkovic2010towards,
  title={Towards a spectral theory of graphs based on the signless Laplacian, II},
  author={Cvetkovi{\'c}, Drago{\v{s}} and Simi{\'c}, Slobodan K},
  journal={Linear Algebra and its Applications},
  volume={432},
  number={9},
  pages={2257--2272},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Inspite of having References and the main tex file in the same folder and running them alternatively for 3-4 times I am getting the following error message:

**Error Message**

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "document"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

Process exited normally
```

**The Output file is also not produced properly**

Here is a picture of the Output Produced:

[image]

Can anyone kindly help me out?
Please help me.

Comment: You should call biber not bibtex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer; i am not getting it, please explain where it is wrong

Comment: You are (somehow) starting bibtex: `Process started: bibtex.exe "document"`. This is wrong, biblatex needs biber. See here for a list about how to setup your editor to use biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: @UlrikeFischer; Thank you very much, your advice worked

Comment: @UlrikeFischer; do you know any way to order the citations "alphabetically" in descending order in which they are published, i will be grateful for hellp

Comment: For the sorting you may want to try `sorting=ydnt,` (if I understand correctly), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864. If that doesn't do what you want, I suggest you ask a new question (as this question is about not running Biber).

Comment: @moewe; your linked answer heped a lot, thank you very much