# Why biblatex change cite numbers?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I wants to cite my document in latex(overleaf).
and I used biblatex .
but then i saw after compiling it's numbers changing in wrong  form and one of them disappearing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,a4paper]{article}
\title{hw3}
\author{alisafarpoor1108 }
\date{May 2020}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{images/nemad.jpg}
\end{figure}
\vspace{2cm}
\title{Third Homework} 
\author{
IUST
\\
}

\pagebreak
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\listoffigures
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{CRITERION}
salam\cite{1}\cite{2}\cite{3}\cite{4}\cite{5}\cite{6}\cite{7}\cite{8}

\medskip
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and my lib.blb is:

```
@article{1,
  author  = {M. Xi and L. Chen and D. Polajnar and and W. Tong}, 
  title   = {Local binary pattern network: A deep learning approach for face recognition,},
  journal = {IEEE International Conference on Image Processing (ICIP)},
  year    = 2016,
  pages   = {3224-3228},
}
@article{2,
  author  = {J. Deng and J. Guo and N. Xue and S. Zafeiriou}, 
  title   = {ArcFace: Additive Angular Margin Loss for Deep Face Recognition,},
journal = {IEEE/CVF Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},  
  year    = 2019, 
  pages   = {4685-4694},  
  note    = {An optional note},   
}  
@online{3,  
  author = {O. Kharkovyna},
  title = {An Intro to Deep Learning for Face Recognition,},
  year = 2019,
  url = {https://towardsdatascience.com/an-intro-to-deep-learning-for-face-recognition-aa8dfbbc51fb},
  urldate = {2020-03-30}
}

@book{4,
  author    = {X. Jiang and A. Hadid and Y. Pang and E. Granger }, 
  title     = {Deep Learning in Object Detection and Recognition},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = 2019,
  isbn      = {9811051518}
}

@article{5,
  author  = {P. S. Chandran and N. B. Byju and R. U. Deepak and K. N. Nishakumari and P. Devanand and P. M. Sasi}, 
  title   = {Missing Child Identification System Using Deep Learning and Multiclass SVM,},
  journal = { IEEE Recent Advances in Intelligent Computational Systems (RAICS)},
  year    = 2018,
  pages   = {113-116},
}

@article{6,
  author  = {J. Yu and D. Ko and H. Moon and M. Jeon}, 
  title   = {Deep Discriminative Representation Learning for Face Verification and Person Re-Identification on Unconstrained Condition,},
  journal = {IEEE 25th International Conference on Image Processing (ICIP)},
  year    = 2018,
  pages   = {1658-1662},
}

@article{7,
  author  = {J. Zeng and J. Zeng and X. Qiu}, 
  title   = {Deep learning based forensic face verification in videos,},
  journal = {International Conference on Progress in Informatics and Computing (PIC)},
  year    = 2017,
  pages   = {77-80},
}

@article{8,
  author  = {D. Voth}, 
  title   = {Face recognition technology,},
  journal = {IEEE Intelligent Systems},
  year    = 2003,
  pages   = {4-7},
}
```

but in output i see like the image with wrong citation.
for making it simple I removed most parts but remaining that is here is still wrong.

[image]
'''

Comment: entry 1 if faulty, you have two `and` in the author name. Beside this: don't use numbers as keys, better something like `Xi-Chen.2016`. The keys are not used in the document, they are there to identify an entry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer
thank you , as i understood  i have to change "@article{8," for example as you said and chang 8 to sth else?
i did it and i removed some authors but again they are not in true range:
8 2 4 3 1 5 6 7

Comment: Since you do not specify any bibliography style, it appears that the default style sorts your citation by alphabetical order of the first author. If you want the bibliography entries to appear by citation order, you have to modify `biblatex` options. You might have a look at the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order) in order to see how to do so.

Comment: your references are sorted by biblatex/biber alphabetically, and then numbered. You can change this. There are many options here.

Comment: thank you UlrikeFischer and KersouMan
it is totally worked.
so as above comments i changed keys and then using "and"  and using sort=none.