# How to order citations in References by appearance, but still have author-year labels appearing in the text (besides numbers)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Hi Based on previous post How to order citations by appearance using BibTeX? ,

I tried randomly things like `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, ..., but I don't numbers in the body of the paper

I also tried using

```
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress ]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{...}
```

However, the first line seemed to do nothing except produce the message `Natbib error : Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations`

which slowed down things without influencing the outcome.What to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  As far as I understood, you want author-year like references in your text but sort the references in your bibliography in the order of appearance instead of alphabetically. Is that correct? How is the reader supposed to find a reference in the bibliography then?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management, I suggest that you (a) load the package with the option `authoryear` and (b) employ the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.

[image]

That said, I'd like to repeat the concern voiced in @leandriis' comment: Assuming your paper cites more than half a dozen pieces, how on earth are your readers supposed to find the bibliographic entries that correspond to the citation call-outs? If you wish to employ authoryear-style citation call-outs, I really can't see a valid reason for *not* sorting the entries alphabetically by authors' surnames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="A",title="Aa",year=3001}
@misc{z,author="Z",title="Zz",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{z}, \cite{a}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks.  Indeed, there is a problem. In the example I had seen, the text contained besides authoryear the appearance order number, and the same in the references. Without numbers, it is useless :(

Comment: @florin - Please clarify what you meant by "I don't numbers in the body of the paper" in your posting. I had interpreted it as meanbing that you did not want numbers in the citation call-outs. However, this interpretation may have been wrong.

Comment: @florin I would recommend using the biblatex package ` \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`. Here how to do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order

Comment: @Mico, sdaza, numbers need to appear , but the order I want is that of citation in the text (This allows attempting to sort the papers in order of importance to the topic).  I used sdaza's suggestion \usepackage[natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none]{biblatex} \bibliography{Pare37.bib} (in preamble). Funnily, no reference section appeared, and the names of references in the text were those assigned by me in the bib file