# Sorting bibliography by order of appearance in main document. using a .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm having trouble getting my bibliography sorted so that nr. 1 is the first one referenced in the document. the bibliography list it self is sorted by numbers, but I want to change it so that it follows the use of them in the article.
I'm using a .bib file and importing it using \printbibliography to call it. I'm using \usepackage{biblatex}
but it still doesn't yield the results I want. am I missing something obvious?
I've included my packages and my document set up for clarity:

````
\usepackage[margin=3.75cm]{geometry}
\setlength\headheight{22.660004pt}
\usepackage[table,hyperref,dvipsnames, breaklinks]{xcolor}
\usepackage{incgraph,tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{references.bib} ```

here is a shortend version of my document:
```\begin{document}

\incgraph[documentpaper,
  overlay={\node[red] at (page.center) {};}]
  [width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{Figurer/Forside notat.png}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Afsnit/000_Abstract}
\newpage
  
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Afsnit/00_Forord}
\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\input{Afsnit/28_Refleksion}
\input{Afsnit/29_Konklusion}


\newpage
\printbibliography
\newpage
````

hope somebody can help

Comment: `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864