# Glossary - Resize columns widths / space between columns

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I am in need of your help.

I tried to make a glossary for acronyms. I'm compiling with LuaLaTeX and currently use the printnoidxglossaries with the glossary-longbooktabs package, as the long-booktabs custom style is quite what I would like to have.

However, I am not sure of how to customize this glossary further.

For starters, I would like to respace the columns, so that there is more space between the columns and in the same move, less empty space to the right.
Especially this long width of the "Description" column is a bit upsetting, especially for very short descriptions.
Is there a possibility to resize the length of the horizontal line?

For advance customization: Does anyone know whether you can center the text as well?

Thanks a lot!

Example snippet of the code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook} % one-sided

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % english is the same as american or USenglish
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
url=true,
style=chem-angew, % alphabetic, numeric
sorting=none, % default == nty, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order
maxnames=4,
minnames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex} 
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for better looking table creations, but bad with vertical lines by design (package creator despises vertical lines)
\usepackage[final]{microtype} %resize the text
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc,symbols]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{Exp1}{Exp1}{Test 1}
\newacronym{Exp2}{Exp2}{Test 2}
\newacronym{Exp3}{Exp3}{Test 3}



\begin{document}


\selectlanguage{english}

\frontmatter{}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}


\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym, nogroupskip, style=long-booktabs, nonumberlist]
 %style=long-booktabs
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\mainmatter{}

\gls{Exp1}
\gls{Exp2}
\gls{Exp3}

\end{document}
```

![Spacing problem]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gjVn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook} % one-sided

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % english is the same as american or USenglish
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
url=true,
style=chem-angew, % alphabetic, numeric
sorting=none, % default == nty, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order
maxnames=4,
minnames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex} 
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for better looking table creations, but bad with vertical lines by design (package creator despises vertical lines)
\usepackage[final]{microtype} %resize the text
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc,symbols]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Solution %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossarystyle{my-long-booktabs}{
\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\glsdescwidth}}}
{\end{longtable}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{Exp1}{Exp1}{Test 1}
\newacronym{Exp2}{Exp2}{Test 2}
\newacronym{Exp3}{Exp3}{Test 3}
\newacronym{Exp4}{Long Example notation}{very very very very very very long description for this example}



\begin{document}


\selectlanguage{english}

\frontmatter

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}


\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym, nogroupskip, style=my-long-booktabs, nonumberlist]
 %style=long-booktabs
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\mainmatter

\gls{Exp1}
\gls{Exp2}
\gls{Exp3}
\gls{Exp4}

\end{document}
```

[image]