# Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders

Tags: bibtex, legal-style

Anybody have any idea on how to create the proper APA entry for an Executive Order in my .bib?  I can't seem to find any guidance on what fields to use to make it work.

The reference should appear like this:

Exec. Order No. 13,423, 3 C.F.R. 3919. (2007).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Perhaps you could also show an example of or what is typically included in such a reference?

Comment: Thank you!  Typically, they are seen like this: Exec. Order No. 13,423, 3 C.F.R. 3919. (2007).

Comment: Are you concerned about the format of the reference or the citation (or both?).  I would recommend `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: @AlanMunn mostly what information needs to be in the .bib file so that it appears in the format as shown above.

Comment: And how should the reference look when you cite it in your document?

Comment: @jon That was going to be a follow-up question, since I don't actually cite the reference in the document but wish to include it in the references.

Comment: Well the easiest part of your problem is to 'cite' the reference without having it appear.  Imagine the bib key is 'eo13423'; then you just use `\nocite{eo13423}` and it will be included in your reference list.  also, you could consider using an `@misc` entry that just contains `title` (which holds all the information except the date) and `year`.  If you aren't going to cite it in the document, this would be an easy solution.

Comment: Take a look at the extensive suggestions on BIBTeX at http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/node22.html, that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @jon Thats an interesting workaround. Nice idea.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the answer.  Is there a good tutorial document that you can steer me towards for learning about Biblatex?

Comment: I think the best information is to be found here on the site.  The `biblatex` manual, although extensive, is more of a reference manual than a tutorial, unfortunately.  We have some great questions though: [What to do to switch to biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/2693); [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/2693); [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2693); [How to use `biber`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26516/2693).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do this with more than a hack, it would be best to use `biblatex`.  Here's a sample using the `apa` style for `biblatex`.

Create a new `.bib` entry type

First we create a new bib entry type for executive orders. This allows us to enter the information properly rather than all in one line as would be necessary if you use the `misc` entry type.  Most bibliography managers should allow you to create new entry types.  So an `@executiveorder` entry has the following fields:

```
@executiveorder{Executive-Order2007,
        Number = {13423},
        Pages = {919},
        Volume = {3},
        Year = {2007}}
```

Plus an optional `Note` field.

Then we use `biblatex` to create a new bibliography driver for this entry type.

```
\documentclass{article}
% The following bib file contains a new entry type @executiveorder
% The required fields are Number, Pages, Volume and Year.
% The note field can also be used optionally
% Any other fields will be ignored

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@executiveorder{Executive-Order2007,
    Number = {13423},
    Pages = {919},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2007}}

@executiveorder{Executive-Order2008,
    Number = {10200},
    Pages = {200},
    Volume = {4},
    Year = {2008}}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}

% Define some fixed texts and abbreviations
% Note that the final punctuation for the abbreviations
% is handled by biblatex
\newcommand*{\execname}{Executive Order}
\newcommand*{\execcitename}{Exec.\ Ord}
\newcommand*{\execnumname}{No}
\newcommand*{\execcitenumname}{No}
\newcommand*{\CFRname}{C.\ F.\ R}

% Make a new driver for the executiveorder entry type
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{executiveorder}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printtext{\execname}
  \newblock
  \printtext{\execnumname}\newunit
  \usebibmacro{execnumber}
  \newunit\addcomma\newblock
  \usebibmacro{execvolume}%
  \newblock
  \printtext{\CFRname}%
  \adddot\newunit
  \usebibmacro{execpage}%
  \newblock\newunit
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:finpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Now define macros to print the parts of the reference itself
\newbibmacro*{execnumber}{%
  \printfield[execnumber]{number}
  %
  }
\newbibmacro*{execvolume}{%
  \printfield[execvolume]{volume}
  }
% The page reference is composed of the Volume+page without a space
\newbibmacro*{execpage}{%
  \usebibmacro{execvolume}
  \unspace
  \printfield[execpage]{pages}
  \newunit
  }

% formatting directives for the parts of the executive order
\DeclareFieldFormat{execnumber}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{execvolume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{execpage}{#1}

% since Exec. Orders have no author, we adapt the noname cite macro
% to test for this entry type and use it to format the citation

\renewbibmacro*{cite:noname}{%
    \ifentrytype{executiveorder}{%
    \printtext{\execcitename}
    \adddot\newunit
    \printtext{\execcitenumname}
    \adddot\newunit
    \printfield[execnumber]{number}}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}



\begin{document}
\section*{What did the President do?}
The President, in  \cite{Executive-Order2007} ordered something.
He ordered something else the next year. \parencite{Executive-Order2008}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I guess that these days, you'd use bib strings?

Comment: @cfr Yes, probably. I haven't kept up much on that.

Comment: Hey @AlanMunn, I tried using your MWE as suggested, however it throws an error when compiling: ! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'labelyear+extrayear' undefined.

Comment: @user168390 This is unfortunately an old answer, and various things have changed in `biblatex` in the meantime. I'll see if I can update it to work with current `biblatex`.

Comment: @user168390 For a very detailed explanation of how to do this using modern `biblatex` see [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @AlanMunn :) I actually tried to figure things out for the 7 hours now and went all the way back to try the linked example with Lualatex and my basic class and bib configurations and it breaks already, so I assume, this is just too big for me and give up :)