# Citing a speech in BibTex

Tags: bibtex

I would like to cite [Alan Greenspan's speech](http://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1996/19961205.htm) from 1996. What should the appropriate bibtex entry look like?

Comment: Interesting question. But did you really listen to the speech in person, or did you consume another medium (video, transcript) that you could cite?

Comment: @mafp makes a good point. The question isn't really about `bibtex` unless you have some specific citation/bibliography style (APA, MLA etc.) that specifies what needs to be present etc. See: [Citing a speech in APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2009/10/how-to-cite-a-speech-in-apa-style.html). For a one-off use, you can use the `misc` entry type, but for works involving lots of speeches, a more nuanced approach might be necessary.  See, for example [Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98512) which shows how to create and use a custom entry.

Comment: @mafp, I consumed the transcript that I linked to in the question.

Comment: Then you have a website to cite, and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/21591) might help.

Comment: If you want to cite that web page and you are using `biblatex` the most appropriate entry type is `online`, in my opinion. But if the citation is referred to the speech, `misc` is probably better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't give much to go on in terms of what bibliographical style you need/want.  But you could do something like this for `BibTeX`

```
% usage: latex <file>, bibtex <file>, latex <file>, latex <file>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{greenspan1996,
  author =       {Greenspan, Alan},
  title =        {The Challenge of Central Banking in a Democratic
                  Society},
  year =         {1996},
  month =        {12},
  note =         {Remarks by Chairman Alan Greenspan at the Annual
                  Dinner and Francis Boyer Lecture of The American
                  Enterprise Institute for Public Policy Research,
                  Washington, D.C. [Accessed: 2013 06 20]},
url ={http://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1996/19961205.htm},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

I read: \cite{greenspan1996}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

However, I recommend using `biblatex` (and `biber`).  Even the default output looks much better in my opinion:

```
% usage: latex <file>, biber <file>, latex <file>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{greenspan1996,
  author =   {Greenspan, Alan},
  title =    {The Challenge of Central Banking in a Democratic
                  Society},
  date =     {1996-12-05},
  url = {http://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/speeches/1996/19961205.htm},
  note =     {Remarks by Chairman Alan Greenspan at the Annual
                  Dinner and Francis Boyer Lecture of The American
                  Enterprise Institute for Public Policy Research,
                  Washington, D.C.},
  urldate =      {2013-06-20}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}  

I read: \cite{greenspan1996}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```