# biblatex set author font based on bib field

Tags: biblatex, formatting

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@BOOK{b1,
  author = { first1 last1},
  title = {title1},
  year = {1993},
  note = {tt}
}
@BOOK{b2,
    author = { first2 last2},
    title = {title2},
    year = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
text \footcite{b1} text.
text \footcite{b2} haha. 
\end{document}
```

I want to achieve that the author of b1, which has some keyword in the `note` field, in this case `tt`, is formatted with `\texttt{}` while entries which don't have the keyword in the note field, are formatted in a standard way. There is nothing else in the note field than the keyword.

So, expanded it should give

```
\texttt{last1}, title1
last2, title2
```

in the footnotes as well as in the bibliography instead of 
[image: this current result].

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are looking for the `\iffieldequalstr` command. In the [current version of the biblatex documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) it is in section 4.6.2 on page 182.

Comment: If you can use the `keyword` field (which will not be printed, unlike the `note` field) you just need `\ifkeyword{tt}`. Alternatively you can use the `options` field but then you will have to do a bit more work to set things up nicely. What do you need this for in your document? Maybe there is an easier solution.

Comment: I just have a lot of anonymous sources which are formatted like author = {P/L/51-65/T} and want to use a monospace font for the author to line them all up nicely to be easier to read.

Comment: OK, would using they `keywords` field be an option for you? Or do you prefer the `note` field? (That is do you want the output or not?) But maybe using an `author` field for anonymous sources such as this isn't the best idea in the first place ...

Comment: Ok but how do I actually do the formatting? in the preamble I guess. I'd have to read through the biblatex docs. Any biblatex pros here?

Comment: keywords is fine

Comment: Oh, didn't know. What's the best way for anonymous source. Would it change my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual sources look like. There is always the option to leave the `author` field blank. What you seem to put there is some kind of call number (?), but then certain kinds of "archive material" can be hard to handle.

Comment: it's some kind of chiffre, with some info after every slash. sth like country/city/age/alphacode. the chiffre is explained in the text.

Comment: If that in a way (uniquely) "identifies" an author (much like pseudonym) it is probably still suited for the `author` field.

Comment: @WillieWong Do you want to write up an answer? Maybe not only using `\iffieldequalstr` but also `\ifkeyword` (I find the latter cleaner in this situation).

Comment: Would it make sense to define a new type for such anonymous sources? Then you could define an author format for that type.

Comment: whatever works, really. I can just search and replace book with [new type here] for my anonymous sources.

Comment: found \DeclareFieldFormat[anonymous]{author}{\texttt{#1}\space}. How do I declare my new anonymous type?

Comment: @Philipp Here's a fully worked out example that might help: [Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98512)

Comment: @moewe: go ahead. I don't have much time to write up a complete answer (hence the comment). I agree that `\ifkeyword` would be cleaner. After reading the comments I personally prefer Alan's option of creating a new entry type. But I can see situations where having the keyword based answer can be helpful (for example, multiple different keywords that can stack).

Comment: For name-like fields, you cannot use `\DeclareFieldFormat` you need `\DeclareNameFormat`. But for changes in the font for names you will want to use `\mkbibnamelast` and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do here it might be a good idea to create a new entry type, see [Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98512/35864) and the slightly more involved [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864).

Changing the author font depending on the `keyword`s field, which I think is better suited for this task than the `note` field, is not very hard

```
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\ifkeyword{chiffreauthor}{\texttt{#1}}{#1}}
```

makes sure to print all entries with the keyword `chiffreauthor` in a typewriter font.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{b1,
  author   = {first1 last1},
  title    = {title1},
  year     = {1993},
  keywords = {chiffreauthor},
}
@BOOK{b2,
    author = { first2 last2},
    title  = {title2},
    year   = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\ifkeyword{chiffreauthor}{\texttt{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
text \footcite{b1} text.
text \footcite{b2} haha. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make use of the `note` field, which is going to be printed, you can use

```
\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\iffieldequalstr{note}{chiffreauthor}{\texttt{#1}}{#1}}
```

Comment: Note that I would strongly advocate creating a new type if the relevant entries don't fit into the existing scheme of entry types, if they are interviews, survey/study reports or the like. But I don't see a point in creating a different entry types for say books with "anonymous" authors, when there is already the type `@book`.

Comment: What version was this tested on? Running texlive  2015.20160320 on Kubuntu 16.04, the above MWE produces identical formatting for both footnotes.

Comment: @Supernormal Judging by the date it would have been either `biblatex` 3.0 or 3.1, so quite a few versions ago. If you are running 3.3 or above you need `\mkbibnamefamily` instead of `\mkbibnamelast`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864

Comment: @Supernormal Depending on what exactly you want to do there are more elegant methods to do this and related things now. Field annotations come to mind: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349570/35864