# Overloading Author+an / highlighting more than one author

Tags: biblatex, bold, highlighting, annotations

This is a question related to an answer given by @PLK in [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex) (I am unable to comment in the original post). I want to highlight specific authors in the bibliography. Modifying @PLK's MWE below I want to highlight multiple authors, but this method only highlights one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @MISC{test,
  AUTHOR    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
  AUTHOR+an = {2=highlight,3=highlight},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), pp. 74-75 you need to separate the annotation for different list items (names) with a semicolon

```
@misc{test,
  author    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
  authot+an = {2=highlight;3=highlight},
}
```

works

The syntax is explained as follows

> ```
> <annotationspecs> ::= <annotationspec> [ ";" <annotationspec> ]
> <annotationspec>  ::= [ <itemcount> [ ":" <part> ] ] "=" <annotations>
> <annotations>     ::= <annotation> [ "," <annotation> ]
> <annotation>      ::= (string)
> ```

You want to give different specifications (namely one for item no 2 and one for item no 3). If you separate the two entries with a comma as you did, `biblatex` interprets `3=highlight` as another annotation for the second name.