# How may Biblatex with authoryear be forced to show inline the first name initial of just two authors?

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex with the authoryear style automatically and usefully tries to disambiguate inline authors with identical last names. For instance, if I cited both F. Howell and W.W. Howell, with `\parencite{Howell1951}` and `\parencite{Howell1975}` it would produce:

> These were made to contrast with the earlier "progressive
>   Neanderthals" in the context of the now superseded pre-Neanderthal
>   hypothesis (F. Howell 1951),  but they are now taken to contrast with
>   Southwest Asian Neanderthals as well (W. Howell 1975).

In my case, however, the second author is not W.W. Howell, but W.W. Howells with an s. Hence, Biblatex would not disambiguate:

> These were made to contrast with the earlier "progressive
>   Neanderthals" in the context of the now superseded pre-Neanderthal
>   hypothesis (Howell 1951),  but they are now taken to contrast with
>   Southwest Asian Neanderthals as well (Howells 1975).

I would like it to disambiguate anyway so that someone reading fast would not think those two authors are the same person and someone reading slow does not think it's a typo. I would like it to produce:

> These were made to contrast with the earlier "progressive
>   Neanderthals" in the context of the now superseded pre-Neanderthal
>   hypothesis (F. Howell 1951),  but they are now taken to contrast with
>   Southwest Asian Neanderthals as well (W.W. Howells 1975).

How may this be done?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt, style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=1, doi=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{Howell1951,
title = {Some title},
year = {1951},
author = {F. Howell},
journal = {Some journal}
}
@article{Howells1975,
title = {Another title},
year = {1975},
author = {W.W. Howells},
journal = {Another journal}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}



    \begin{document}

Blabla \parencite{Howell1951},  bla blo \parencite{Howells1975}. 

    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Mhhh, this is done automatically by Biber and since the names are obviously different, currently no disambiguation is done - one would have to manipulate how Biber works. You can do that manually though, if you like.

Comment: @moewe There's no quick and dirty way or workaround to ask Biber to print the first name initials ("F. Howell" and "W.W. Howells") just for these two authors? How may I do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of letting Biber do that automatically on some kind of 'fuzzy similarity' basis. But you can do that manually.

Use the annotation feature explained by PLK in [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864) (see also [Overloading Author+an / highlighting more than one author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349570/35864) and of course [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), pp. 74-75)

```
@article{Howell1951,
  title     = {Some title},
  year      = {1951},
  author    = {F. Howell},
  author+an = {1=initials},
  journal   = {Some journal},
}
@article{Howells1975,
  title     = {Another title},
  year      = {1975},
  author    = {W. W. Howells},
  author+an = {1=initials},
  journal   = {Another journal},
}
```

Where you can give `initials` or `full` in the `+an` field for the corresponding item to print initials or the full name.

Then redefine `labelname` to

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{uniquename}}{1}} and test {\ifitemannotation{initials}}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{1}}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{uniquename}}{2}} and test {\ifitemannotation{full}}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{2}}
    {}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

this resets the counter for name disambiguation to a higher value that shows more (i.e. initials or the full first name) if requested by `initials` or `full`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt, style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=1, doi=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Howell1951,
  title     = {Some title},
  year      = {1951},
  author    = {F. Howell},
  author+an = {1=initials},
  journal   = {Some journal},
}
@article{Howells1975,
  title     = {Another title},
  year      = {1975},
  author    = {W. W. Howells},
  author+an = {1=initials},
  journal   = {Another journal},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{uniquename}}{1}} and test {\ifitemannotation{initials}}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{1}}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{uniquename}}{2}} and test {\ifitemannotation{full}}}
    {\setcounter{uniquename}{2}}
    {}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
Blabla \parencite{Howell1951},  bla blo \parencite{Howells1975}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Hmm, your MWE does not work on my machine. Among other errors, I get "Undefined control sequence.<argument> \ifitemannotation{initials} Blabla \parencite{Howell1951}" and "Package bib latex Error: Bibliography macro 'name:family' undefined."

Comment: @TheThunderChimp Some of the methods used here are fairly recent, so it could be that your `biblatex` and Biber are outdated. You require at least ?`biblatex` 3.4/Biber 2.5, the current versions are 3.7/2.7. Make an update of both `biblatex` and Biber via your TeX distribution.