# Biblatex not working

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to get `biblatex` to work. I tried different examples but finally found one from this forum. However, I always get an error on the `\cite` command (see latex output below)

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{refs.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Hello\cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 

\end{document} 



running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
pdflatex>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex>  Source specials enabled.
pdflatex> entering extended mode
pdflatex> (./document.tex
pdflatex> LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
pdflatex> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
pdflatex> rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
pdflatex> c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
pdflatex> h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
pdflatex> h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
pdflatex> ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
pdflatex> rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
pdflatex> kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
pdflatex>  polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
pdflatex> lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
pdflatex> welsh, loaded.
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
pdflatex> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./refs.bib'.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
pdflatex> (biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
pdflatex> (biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
pdflatex> (/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
pdflatex> (./document.aux
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> ! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option american yet.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> See the babel package documentation for explanation.
pdflatex> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
pdflatex>  ...                                              
pdflatex>                                                   
pdflatex> l.5 \select@language{american}
pdflatex>                               
pdflatex> ) (./document.bbl)
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.218 Hello\cite{KandR}
pdflatex>                        
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'KandR' on page 1 undefined on input line 218.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 219.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
pdflatex> (./document.aux)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex>  )
pdflatex> (see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2012/te
pdflatex> xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
pdflatex> mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 22927 bytes).
pdflatex> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex> Transcript written on document.log.
running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/bibtex document 
bibtex> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
bibtex> The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
bibtex> I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> (There were 3 error messages)
running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
pdflatex>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex>  Source specials enabled.
pdflatex> entering extended mode
pdflatex> (./document.tex
pdflatex> LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
pdflatex> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
pdflatex> rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
pdflatex> c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
pdflatex> h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
pdflatex> h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
pdflatex> ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
pdflatex> rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
pdflatex> kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
pdflatex>  polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
pdflatex> lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
pdflatex> welsh, loaded.
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
pdflatex> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./refs.bib'.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
pdflatex> (biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
pdflatex> (biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
pdflatex> (/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
pdflatex> (./document.aux) (./document.bbl)
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.218 Hello\cite{KandR}
pdflatex>                        
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'KandR' on page 1 undefined on input line 218.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 219.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
pdflatex> (./document.aux)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex>  )
pdflatex> (see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2012/te
pdflatex> xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
pdflatex> mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 22927 bytes).
pdflatex> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex> Transcript written on document.log.
running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
pdflatex>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex>  Source specials enabled.
pdflatex> entering extended mode
pdflatex> (./document.tex
pdflatex> LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
pdflatex> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
pdflatex> rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
pdflatex> c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
pdflatex> h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
pdflatex> h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
pdflatex> ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
pdflatex> rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
pdflatex> kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
pdflatex>  polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
pdflatex> lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
pdflatex> welsh, loaded.
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
pdflatex> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./refs.bib'.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
pdflatex> (biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
pdflatex> (biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
pdflatex> (/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
pdflatex> (./document.aux) (./document.bbl)
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.218 Hello\cite{KandR}
pdflatex>                        
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'KandR' on page 1 undefined on input line 218.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 219.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
pdflatex> (./document.aux)
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
pdflatex> (biblatex)                document
pdflatex> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex>  )
pdflatex> (see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2012/te
pdflatex> xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
pdflatex> mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
pdflatex> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 22927 bytes).
pdflatex> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex> Transcript written on document.log.
```

Using this example: [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber)

I get the following errors even though the backend is set to biber

```
running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
pdflatex>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex>  Source specials enabled.
pdflatex> entering extended mode
pdflatex> (./document.tex
pdflatex> LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
pdflatex> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
pdflatex> rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
pdflatex> c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
pdflatex> h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
pdflatex> h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
pdflatex> ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
pdflatex> rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
pdflatex> kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
pdflatex>  polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
pdflatex> lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
pdflatex> welsh, loaded.
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
pdflatex> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
pdflatex> (/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-natbib.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear-icomp.bbx
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear.bbx
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-icomp.cbx
pdflatex> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Package csquotes Warning: No multilingual support.
pdflatex> (csquotes)                Cannot enable multilingual quotes on input line 246.
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
pdflatex> (./document.aux) (./document.bbl)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
pdflatex> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
pdflatex> ))) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
pdflatex> (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
pdflatex> (./document.out) (./document.out)
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.247 ...m ipsum dolor sit amet~\cite{kastenholz}.
pdflatex>                                                   
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.248 ...o dolores et ea rebum~\cite{sigfridsson}.
pdflatex>                                                   
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> \biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
pdflatex>                           =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
pdflatex> l.250 \end
pdflatex>           {document}
pdflatex> 
pdflatex> Overfull \hbox (7.21625pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 250--250
pdflatex> [][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Kastenholz, M. A. and Philippe H. H^^?unenberger (2006). \ 
pdflatex>  Com-pu-ta-tion of method-
pdflatex> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
pdflatex> (./document.aux) )
pdflatex> (see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2012/te
pdflatex> xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
pdflatex> mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
pdflatex> mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf
pdflatex> -dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-
pdflatex> dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
pdflatex> Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 62794 bytes).
pdflatex> SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
pdflatex> Transcript written on document.log.
```

Comment: You should use Biber rather than BibTeX or add the `backend=BibTeX` option to `biblatex`.

Comment: Maybe I should update to tex 2013 version. Even though 2012 definitely has the biblatex installed. I checked that

Comment: In your log I see a suspicious file `/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty` which is probably the culprit. Remove it: it is from a very old package for HTML generation that is now obsolete and dangerous. Try first changing its name if you don't feel like deleting it.

Comment: Haaa! Amazing! removing the url.sty fixed the problem. Whatever it was. fantastic :-) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The first error reported, that is

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option american yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \select@language{american}
```

is probably due to the fact that you removed the line `\usepackage[american]{babel}` for producing the minimal example. Indeed there's no trace of it any more in the later runs of `pdflatex`.

The second problem is

```
running: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/bibtex document 
bibtex> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
bibtex> The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
bibtex> I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
bibtex> (There were 3 error messages)
```

Since you are using `biblatex` the default tool for processing the `.bib` file is `biber` rather than `bibtex`. So either you use `biber` or specify

```
backend=BibTeX
```

in the options to `biblatex` (it's recommended switching to `biber`, though).

The third error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
                         =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
l.218 Hello\cite{KandR}
```

This is due to a bogus `url.sty` file that you have in

```
/Users/wolfgang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty
```

and with high probability is an infamous `url.sty` that an old package for HTML conversion from LaTeX provided. Remove the entire `html` folder. If you don't feel like deleting it, make a ZIP archive of it and then remove the folder.