# Natbib: How to suppress the same author in case of multiple citations?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

My problem is simple. In my document, in order to produce references, I use natbib. When I have the same author I prefer to have hers/his name to appear once (in the beginning) and then instead of his full name I want to have a 3-em baseline.

Is this possible to happen?

Here is a simple code:

```
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage[sectionbib, sort]{natbib}

\author{My name}
\title{Suppressing same author's name in multiple citations}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

As it is mentioned in \cite{Card2005} and \cite{Card2012} ... 


\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

where the bibliography file (biblio.bib) contains:

```
@ARTICLE{Card2005,
  author = {Card, David},
  title = {{Is the New Immigration Really so Bad?}},
  journal = {Economic Journal},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {115},
  pages = {F300--F323},
  number = {507},
  month = {November},
  timestamp = {2013.06.19}
}

@ARTICLE{Card2012,
  author = {Card, David},
  title = {{Comment: The Elusive Search for Negative Wage Impacts of Immigration}},
  journal = {Journal of the European Economic Association},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {211--215},
  number = {1},
  timestamp = {2013.06.25}
}
```

Comment: If you are willing to switch to `biblatex` this is easy; and, for what it is worth, `chicagoa` dates from 1992 (and was designed for LaTeX 2.09!) and therefore implements the 13th edition *Chicago Manual of Style*, which was published in 1982 (14th = 1993; current is 16th).  `biblatex` has an up-to-date contributed 'Chicago' style, called `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: This seems to be possible with `natbib`, have a look at [American Naturalist BibTeX BST style file (amnatnat.bst)](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.de/2007_08_01_archive.html) and [The McBride bibliography style (mcbridge.bst)](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/McBride/). However `biblatex` offers a wider range of trackers and options.

Comment: @jon How the code above can be used with biblatex and get the result that I want. Also, I have a specific bibliography style that I have manually installed in the MikTex system. Is the declaration of bibliography style the same as in Natbib?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [`biblatex` for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) might give you a quick overview of how `biblatex` works. Custom `.bst` cannot be used with `biblatex`, but it is very easy to modify one of the existing styles to your needs, see for example [Guidelines for Customizing `biblatex` styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/). Though the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is quite daunting, `biblatex` is quite easy to use.

Comment: @moewe It seems that I need to learn everything from the very beginning. Maybe I will do that later, but for now, I will continue using natbib, for it fits much better my needs (it has hypperrefs, coloured citations) and with the assistance of some other codes that I have found in the forum it is quite good. I know biblatex is the future, and I will devote sometime in the future.

Comment: @moewe Your comments would make a fine answer.

Comment: @lockstep Sure, maybe you like to improve the answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

As @jon has pointed out in the comments above `chicagoa` is quite an old implementation of the *Chicago Manual of Style* guidelines way back from 1992.

For `biblatex` there is `biblatex-chicago`, it implements the 16th edition of the CMS and is still actively maintained.

`biblatex-chicago` replaces recurring author names by a dash.

A short example of a file using `biblatex-chicago` would be

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{cicero, wilde, baez/online, baez/article}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Where `biblatex-examples.bib` is a file containing the bibliography. As a matter of fact that particular file is part of the standard `biblatex` installation. Normally you would put `yourbibfile.bib` right in the same directory as the main `.tex` file.

For current versions of `biblatex`, running Biber instead of BibTeX is recommended.
So you would compile the above example via

```
pdflatex test
biber test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

The output should then look like this

[image]

Have a look at

- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864)
- [biblatex for idiots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864)
- [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26516/35864)
- The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (this is a very heavy read)
- The [`biblatex-chicago` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf)

as well