# How to cite bibliography in foot notes using TeXmaker?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, footnotes, citing

I would like to cite bibliography in foot notes using TeXmaker and display **ibid** if I have already cite the work. All the solutions I've found use BibLaTeX but actually I don't see the possibility to compile my `.bib`file with BibLaTeX in TeXmaker but only with BibTeX.
If I type `tlmgr show biblatex` in the terminal it seems installed why I can't use it with teXmaker?Is there a simple way to use it?

Comment: I would suggest you to upgrade to TeXstudio (texstudio is the new name, and version, of TeXmaker). TeXstudio provides immediate support for `biblatex`

Comment: To use `biber`(A BibTeX replacement for biblatex) in TeXmaker: Option 1(simple): Go to `Configure TeXmaker`--> `Commands`  replace default `bibtex %.aux` with `biber %` or Option 2: Go to `User`--> Create a `User Command`--> `Commands`--> by `Edit User Commands` and add Menu `biber` and `Command` as `biber %` and Confirm `Ok`. @Guido You are mistaken texstudio is a fork of texmaker. texmaker name remains the same see [this info](http://tug.org/pipermail/protext/2011q3/000377.html) from it's author.

Comment: @texenthusiast I've tried the second method but when I try to compile my `.tex` file with biber I've an error `Error : could not start the command`. Thanks however!

Comment: @GM Do you have [biber](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) installed via MiKTeX or TeXLive distro, It's usally done by default. on Windows or Linux Type `biber` at Commandline/Terminal to check if it's installed. Use the full path of the executable or add MiKTeX bin to the PATH in windows.

Comment: @texenthusiast I've try to install it with TeX Utilities but the setup fails...Thanks for the  help however! maybe I've to update the packages first, I don't know...

Comment: @GM Usually I prefer same distro TeXLive and same editor TeXmaker on both platforms and makesure to use `backend=biber` option with `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. Also update TeX distro it might help sometimes.

Comment: @texenthusiast but I don't understand I try `tlmgr show biblatex`and I have biblatex installed why I cant use it in texmaker...

Comment: [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is package and [biber](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) is a executable similar to `bibtex` to compile `.bib` files. you would need both `biber` executable and `biblatex` package installed to use it with TeXmaker. Remember TeXmaker is just an front end/IDE to call executables them.

Comment: @texenthusiast `biber`seems install if i type `biber` in terminal I have `Usage:biber etc. etc. `but I've still that error when I run `biber % `with teXmaker... Thank for the help!

Comment: @GM Run a small test via Terminal on example files at [How to use biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34136/15717) to avoid editor and focus on any biber issues.

Comment: @texenthusiast Have run this, I hope is the right way:`iMac-di-Casa:~ User$ biber /Users/user/biblatex-examples.bib
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is '/Users/user/biblatex-example.bib.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file '/Users/giacomo/biblatex-example.bib.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?``
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: @GM copy the code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34136/15717 and run first `pdflatex code-copied-from-link-q` and then save the [examples.bib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib) inside the same folder as `code-copied-from-link-q.tex` and now run `pdflatex code-copied-from-link-q` `biber` and then `pdflatex code-copied-from-link-q` and again `pdflatex code-copied-from-link-q` at terminal. you might not need file-name for biber, since needs `copied-from-link-q.bcf` file in the folder.In TeXmaker configure use `biber %` it works well.