# biblatex-biber: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: biber

I noticed some time ago that `biber` seem to have stopped working for me:

Example taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Results in

> fish: Job 1, “biber test.bcf” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

or in `zsh`

> [1]    21077 segmentation fault (core dumped)  biber test.bcf

[image: Rendered pdf]

Do you have any idea why this happens? I'm running out of ideas...

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

---

Edit: Maybe I should add that I'm using a freshly installed `biblatex-biber 1.8-2` with all the up-to-date perl-dependencies in AUR.

Comment: delete the temporary files of the old biber program. For Linux you'll find the files under `/tmp/par-<hexnumber>`

Comment: There is no `/tmp/par-*`. The only files containing "biber" in `/tmp` are in `/tmp/yaourt-tmp-root/aur-biblatex-biber/` from the reinstalling. Deleting these does not make any differences. :/

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE with that directory. However, run `biber --tool-config`
 and it shows the directory

Answer (score 1):

It works again! \(^_^)/

I noticed a less vacuous message in `/proc/kmsg` which stated the segfault to happen in `Simple.so` from the `perl-date-simple`-package. This raised a cascade of other segfaults but finally after rebuilding

- `perl-date-simple`
- `perl-unicode-gcstring`
- `perl-autovivification` and
- `perl-text-bibtex`

it works again properly.

Due to [this](https://www.archlinux.org/news/perl-updated-to-520/) update, I think that it is an `Arch-Linux` thingy. In this case, if anybody encounters a comparable problem, try rebuilding all the `biblatex-biber` dependencies. You can get them via:

```
pacman -Qi biblatex-biber
```