# Unable to open the bibliography file

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, miktex2.9

hey I am getting the error shown in pic. I am using **TexMaker 4.5** and **Miktex 2.9**

[image: error shown]

Edit 1: Adding minimal work example (MEW)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Kunal Tiwari}
\title{Title}

%\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
%\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear,
%sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}

\addbibresource{24_9_17.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textbf{Title}
\end{large}
 \\
{Kunal Tiwari}
\end{center}

\vspace*{5mm}

 Text text text  \parencite{ref2}. sometext bla bla bla \parencite{ref1}. 

%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%\bibliography{24_9_2017}

\printbibliography[title={References},category=cited]
\end{document}
```

The thing is that this works fine on sharelatex. but I have some issues with the texmaker. I am not able to figure them out and it's causing me to use sharelatex a lot more than I would like.

[image: pic of the warnings I am getting]

edit 2:
Adding the directory structure in picture. Also screenshot of my texMaker settings. 
[image: Directory]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Don't use build folders. They only make life more difficult.

Comment: That was useful comment. I did it. But it still does not solve my problem.

Comment: Is the error still the same? Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? Since you question is about an external programme we would also need to know how you call BibTeX (if you use an editor, take a screenshot of the configuration). If you could also show us your directory structure that would help enormously.

Comment: Any news here? Do things work now? If not, what error(s) do you get? Can you show us an MWE as well as your editor settings and directory structure for the problematic files?

Comment: @moewe I am not getting any error, but there is no reference either.

Comment: Check the `.blg` file, what does it say? How does your folder structure look like? (See my comments above.)

Comment: @moewe cannot spot any .blg file in my directory. Does it get created automatically ?

Comment: That depends. There should definitely be one. You need to make sure to run BibTeX, normally that is the default when you do a 'quick build'. There is a problem with your configuration: In the last screenshot the 'Bib(la)tex' line should read `bibtex %.aux` (note: no space before `bibtex` and `%.aux` it).

Comment: Of course you should look into running Biber, i.e. `backend=biber` and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Well, the problem was `bibtex %.aux` . Now it's fine. Thanks @moewe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX needs to be called on the `.aux` file, so in your last screenshot the 'Bib(la)tex' command should read

```
bibtex %.aux
```

and not just `bibtex`.

---

Since you are using `biblatex`, I'd urge you to consider using Biber. BibTeX is only supported as legacy backend and does not support the full set of `biblatex` features that Biber provides.

With a modern TeX distribution it should be enough to change `backend=bibtex,` to

```
backend=biber,
```

and make your editor call Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

You might also want to read [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26516/35864), [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) as well as [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for background and additional info.