# I can not see the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In my document, I can not see the bibliography. What am I doing wrong?

**Document.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\input{structure}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
\draw (current page.center) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering SolidWorks Básico\\[15pt]
{\Large Curso de SolidWorks}\\[20pt]
{\huge Leandro Carvalho}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2017 Leandro Carvalho\\ notice

\noindent \textsc{Clube de Autores}\\

\noindent \textsc{www.swtutorial.com}\\

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\

\noindent \textit{Primeira Impressão, Outubro 2017}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Conteúdo
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}


\part{Capítulo}

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}
\section{Interface do Usuário}\index{Interface do Usuário}
\section{Aba Esboço}\index{Aba Esboço}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Minitable
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tcbsidebyside[title=Envolver,
sidebyside adapt=left,
bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
]{%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Envolver.png}
    %
}{%
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.
}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Aba Recursos}\index{Aba Recursos}
\section{Mouse}\index{Mouse}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Minitable
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tcbsidebyside[title=Envolver,
sidebyside adapt=left,
bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
]{%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Envolver.png}
    %
}{%
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço. \cite{book_key}
}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Listas}\index{Listas}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Listas!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Definições}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Alças de dimensão ] Para isto é necessário que o usuário clique, segure e arraste a esfera que irá surgir próximo das setas das dimensões.
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Ambiente de peça}

\section{Interface do Usuário}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

\section{Exemplos}\index{Exemplos}

This is an example of examples.

\section{Exercícios}\index{Exercícios}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliografia}}
\section*{Livros}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Livros}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Artigos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Artigos}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

\end{document}
```

**structure.tex**

```
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\graphicspath{{Imagens/}}

\setlist{nolistsep}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts

\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]

% Boxed/framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}% % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

% Non-boxed/non-framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenum}% % Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square
\makeatother

% Defines the theorem text style for each type of theorem to one of the three styles above
\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\theoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
\newtheorem{theoremeT}[dummy]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exerciseT}{Exercise}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumex}
\newtheorem{exampleT}{Example}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumbox}
\newtheorem{vocabulary}{Vocabulary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definitionT}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollaryT}[dummy]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{ocrenum}
\newtheorem{proposition}[dummy]{Proposition}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEFINITION OF COLORED BOXES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

% Theorem box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{tBox}

% Exercise box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}    

% Definition box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt]{dBox}    

% Corollary box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=gray,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{cBox}

% Creates an environment for each type of theorem and assigns it a theorem text style from the "Theorem Styles" section above and a colored box from above
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{tBox}\begin{theoremeT}}{\end{theoremeT}\end{tBox}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}                 
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}   
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}        
\newenvironment{corollary}{\begin{cBox}\begin{corollaryT}}{\end{corollaryT}\end{cBox}}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REMARK ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{remark}{\par\vspace{10pt}\small % Vertical white space above the remark and smaller font size
\begin{list}{}{
\leftmargin=35pt % Indentation on the left
\rightmargin=25pt}\item\ignorespaces % Indentation on the right
\makebox[-2.5pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[draw=ocre!60,line width=1pt,circle,fill=ocre!25,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] at (-15pt,0pt){\textcolor{ocre}{R}};\end{tikzpicture}} % Orange R in a circle
\advance\baselineskip -1pt}{\end{list}\vskip5pt} % Tighter line spacing and white space after remark

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\thepart}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@book{book_key,
    address = {São Paulo},
    publisher = {Clube de Autores},
    author = {carvalho, Leandro},
    title = {SW Tutorial},
    year = {2017},
    volume = {1},
    series = {1},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {123--200},
    month = {January}
}

@article{article_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Article title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {14},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1--8},
    month = {March}
}
```

Comment: do you compile `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`? and do you cite bibitems?

Comment: Your example is currently not a working one, because of missing files like the background image. Can you please reduce your code to a *minimal* working example, that contains only those code, that is necessary to reproduce your problem? However, if I use option `demo` for `graphicx` I get a bibliography (at least Lirvos). So maybe you've forgotten to call `biber`. See also: [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber)

Comment: Maybe related: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: You need to run Biber as explained in the question Schweinebacke linked above. If you use an editor to do these things for you ahve a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Please also check the `.log` and `.blg` files for errors and warnings.

Comment: unrelated to the biliography but don't do this!!!  `\noindent \textsc{Clube de Autores}\\ ` you must get multible warnings about badness 10000, note that is _as the maximum badness possible_ that is TeX is telling you it can not make any reasonable output given that input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Based on your given code I created a MWE, that means I reduced your given code to the minimal size reproducing the error.

In your case--as already mentioned in comments--you are missing the run of biber.

Lets start with the MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book_key,
    address = {São Paulo},
    publisher = {Clube de Autores},
    author = {carvalho, Leandro},
    title = {SW Tutorial},
    year = {2017},
    volume = {1},
    series = {1},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {123--200},
    month = {January}
}
@article{article_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Article title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {14},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1--8},
    month = {March}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[%
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=nyt,
  sortcites=true,
  autopunct=true,
  babel=hyphen, 
  hyperref=true,
  abbreviate=false,
  backref=true,
  backend=biber  
]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file


\begin{document}

text \cite{book_key} text \nocite{*}

\chapter*{Bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliografia}}
\section*{Livros}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Livros}
\printbibliography[%
  heading=bibempty,
  type=book
]
\section*{Artigos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Artigos}
\printbibliography[%
  heading=bibempty,
  type=article
]

\end{document}
```

Please copy it to your computer and save it for example under the name `mwe.tex`.

Now open your terminal/console and start compiling:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

That compile run gives you a new file `mwe.aux` needed for `biber`. Now use command

```
biber mwe
```

to get  two files `mwe.blg` (log file, check it for errors and warnings) and `mwe.bbl`.

Now compile **twice**

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

to finish the TeX document.  Now you should see your bibliography.  If not, check both log files `mwe.log` and `mwe.blg` for errors or warnings ...

Depending on your used editor you can start the run of `biber` after proper configuration of the editor. Please see, if your editor is described in question [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations).

**EDIT by OP:**

Process successfully using TeXworks.

[image]

Now fully functional using TeXstudio.